# How do I set a custom style to given stacked columns?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm struggling with accomplishing this:

I have a stacked column chart with 4 series, and I want the user to be able to click on a stacked column (not an individual column, the whole stacked column) to select those points and to change the width, color, add dataLabels of the selected stacked column only. This is needed to show more detailed information on that selected stacked column.

The series looks like this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'd',
    data: [120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000],
    color: '#ffffff'
}, {
    name: 'c',
    data: [40000, 67000, 94000, 121000, 148000, 175000, 202000, 229000, 256000, 283000, 310000, 337000, 364000, 391000, 418000],
    color: '#bde0db'
}, {
    name: 'b',
    data: [75000, 73000, 71000, 69000, 67000, 65000, 63000, 61000, 59000, 57000, 55000, 53000, 51000, 49000, 47000],
    color: '#a7dcf0'
}, {
    name: 'a',
    data: [450000, 425000, 400000, 375000, 350000, 325000, 300000, 275000, 250000, 225000, 200000, 175000, 150000, 125000, 100000],
    color: '#8dbad2'
}]
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XFDdz/6/ ( thanks to Dmonix for this!! )

Is there any way to do this? If so how?

EDIT: From what I can see here, parts of what I want it is doable ( different width on stacked columns): http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#marimekko-charts and http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2303560-multi-dimensional-column-charts

If anyone could point me in the right direction for the width issue, and the remaning styling and the addition of datalabels for selected stacked column points, I would be much grateful!

EDIT 2: I figured out how to set color to given points, still need to find out how to set the width. Solution in the series noted below:

```
series: [{
    name: 'd',
    data: [120000, 120000, 120000, {name: 'point 1',color: '#df4a92',y:120000,pointWidth:100}, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000, 120000],
    color: '#ffffff'
}, {
    name: 'c',
    data: [40000, 67000, 94000, {name: 'point 1',color: '#81c6bd',y:121000,pointWidth:100}, 148000, 175000, 202000, 229000, 256000, 283000, 310000, 337000, 364000, 391000, 418000],
    color: '#bde0db'
}, {
    name: 'b',
    data: [75000, 73000, 71000, {name: 'point 1',color: '#58c3eb',y:69000,pointWidth:100}, 67000, 65000, 63000, 61000, 59000, 57000, 55000, 53000, 51000, 49000, 47000],
    color: '#a7dcf0'
}, {
    name: 'a',
    data: [450000, 425000, 400000, {name: 'point 1',color: '#2e87b7',y:375000,pointWidth:100}, 350000, 325000, 300000, 275000, 250000, 225000, 200000, 175000, 150000, 125000, 100000],
    color: '#8dbad2'
}]
```

Ignore the pointWidth in the data set, it does nothing..

EDIT 3: I can set the width by manipulating the SVG elements directly, but that is a BAD BAD hack and I really want it to be solved via the API, and this method does not resize/place the rest of the columns:

```
$(".highcharts-series.highcharts-tracker rect[fill='#2e87b7']").attr('width',175)
$(".highcharts-series.highcharts-tracker rect[fill='#58c3eb']").attr('width',175)
$(".highcharts-series.highcharts-tracker rect[fill='#81c6bd']").attr('width',175)
$(".highcharts-series.highcharts-tracker rect[fill='#df4a92']").attr('width',175)
```

Comment: Fixed fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XFDdz/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was to create new SVG elements (with Highcharts.renderer) that match the columns height and position, and then reposition the new elements over the actuall graph. I then reposition the data labels based on a data-rel tag in the new elements, and a matchin css class name in the data labels.

The only (acceptable) drawback is that the column overlaps the previous and the next column.

Since there's no way to do this through the Highcharts API, I accept this answer.